# Expo-CLI in mac os (high sierra)

Tags: react-native, expo

guys I'm having a lot of trouble installing the expo-cli on mac (High Sierra), every time I install it is not going to $ PATH and even if it indicates the path it still does not run, I tried to uninstall and install it again it still doesn't work